# Hanging lights in holes in the front of roof line

Tags: lighting, roof, exterior

We just moved into a new house (newly built) that has these holes all along the roof line

[image: Holes in the roof front]

I was wondering if it would be appropriate to attach something [like these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Accents-Holiday-EZ-Gutter-Hooks-25-Count-81220/202352481) to the holes so that I could hang my Christmas lights from them.  I suspect I can put the notched end into the hole and then wrap the lights line themselves into the other end (basically inverting the way they're supposed to be used).  Since the bulk of the house is plaster, I don't see any other way to really attach lights in this case, short of using something like sticky attachments, which I'm not super-excited about.

I'm open to other suggestions as well.  So, if you have any thoughts, I'd love to hear them.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the holes punched in the metal or the recesses under the tiles? Also, I bet you meant stucco, not plaster.

Comment: @isherwood yes, I mean the holes punched in the metal.  And I tend to think of stucco and plaster as being the same thing in this case, but yes, I meant stucco.

Comment: The don't look large enough, and they're weep holes which probably shouldn't be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Those look to me like ventilation holes for the roofing system. I can't imagine where your hanging Christmas lights from them would be a problem.  Note:  There are far less expensive 'S' hooks available in the hardware section. Also, they will be available in multiple sizes there and will be such that you can bend and form them so to get them to hook into the holes.  Merry Christmas. P.

Comment: Thanks!  However, what about @isherwood's comment above that "they're weep holes which probably shouldn't be blocked"?  I live in AZ so I'm not ENTIRELY concerned about rain issues (if that's what "weep holes" are for), but I want to make sure I'm doing the right things.

Comment: Weep holes are often for condensation, not precipitation.

Comment: In either case the wire hook would not provide any significant blockage.

Comment: as long as you don't cram a fat s-hook in each one and totally seal it, you still have holes.